# Angular2: How Inputs and outputs are changing in RC

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-services, angular2-forms

Since my code is on Angular2 beta I want to update it to RC, I searched but I found latest information about inputs and outputs nowhere, I also want to know the Angular2 documentation, the github repository(where the whole code resides)where I can see the list of decorators because earlier I used inputs and outputs without decorators now i want to take it to further and want to use @Output and @Input decorators, For the future if I want to find latest information where should I find

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that changes are the imports

```
import {Input, Output} from '@angular/core'
```

instead of

```
import {Input, Output} from 'angular2/core'
```

You can find all the changes in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

The change from `angular2` to `@angular` also requires updating your systemjs config. For more details see https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: yes already had quick start, I just wanted to know is there any change in syntax of output or input syntax, are they really as earlier, further I wanted to know the list of decorator so that i could restructure my code around decorators and modules you know some high level functionality rather plan old style plan, so i wanted to peek into documentation which is found on github, could you give me that link